# Create cron job on aws ebs to run a python script

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Elastic BeanStalk server on aws being used as a JSON server.  The data files need to be updated daily.
I have a python script that I want to run every weekday to update the data files. I created .ebextensions folder and created cronjob.config below. I want to run update_data_files.py daily.
I used the template for cronjob.config from : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/

Question:
How do I run this script as cronjob?  what is the path to the uploaded folder in ebs so that the python script will run?

python3 update_data_files.py

.....cronjob.config.....

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            5 16 * * 1-5 root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash
            date > /tmp/date
            # Your actual script content

            python3 update_data_files.py

            exit 0
commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `cronjob.config` file describes two files: `/etc/cron.d/mycron` and `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`.

The first file is placed in the `/etc/cron.d` directory which is one of the places where you put your [cron jobs in Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux). `mycron` file is your cron job in this case, it contains the line:

`5 16 * * 1-5 root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`

which instructs to run `myscript.sh` at 16:05 from Monday to Friday (as a root user). After placing a file in this directory cron will check it automatically and run the jobs at specified times. You don't need to do anything more.

The second file, `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`, is the one that is run by the cron job.

Considering the question where you can find these files - you provided the full paths to them in their names above.

The crons which were setup in the `/etc/cron.d` directory cannot be viewed with the `crontab -l` or `sudo crontab -l` commands, but this doesn't mean that they won't run - the files in this directory are [constantly monitored and parsed as cron jobs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/cron.8.en.html).

If you think your script is not being executed, make a simple test by modifying your cron job. For e.g.:

```
* * * * * root echo $(date) >> /tmp/cron.log; /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

This job will print the current date and time (every 1 minute) to the `cron.log` file created in `/tmp`. After that it will try to execute your command. You can check whether the cron jobs are executed at all by checking this log file.

Then, if your command silently fails, you can redirect the standard output and standard error of your script to some log file to check what goes wrong with its execution.

Comment: Have a look at the link in my answer (under "ssh into the Elastic Beanstalk instance") or at the official [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.ec2connect.html). Anyways, why would you need to get into those directories? Once the `cronjob.config` is specified, everything should work.

Comment: I was finally able to ssh to the instance.  everything is where they should be; myscript.sh is in "/usr/local/bin" and "mycron" is in "/etc/cron.d".  however when I run "crontab -l"    it returns "no crontab for ec2-user!

Comment: This is because you log in as an ec2-user to your system, while in the mycron command you specify `root`, which means that the cronjob is for the root user. Run `sudo crontab -u root -l` - this will show the scheduled crons for the root user. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: When I run "sudo crontab -u root -l" it returns "no crontab for root".  the script didn't get executed.

Comment: I reproduced this and that's right - `crontab -l` will list the cron jobs created only with `crontab -e`, but not the ones scheduled in `/etc/cron.d` directory (which is your case). Generally, these are two different ways of scheduling a cron job. But all this doesn't mean that your script is not executed - check the update in my answer, I gave you some hints.

Comment: With your suggestions I finally was able to debug the issue.  Cronjob is scheduled and is running.  The issue is that the python script I'm trying to execute has several package requirements that were added in requirements.txt seem to be unavailable.  They are available to the Flask API that is running but not to the script that I'm trying to execute with cron!

Comment: Great! Running cron jobs is a bit tricky, the thing is that cron does not inherit your environment (no $PATH, nor other environmental variables, etc) resulting in `command not found` or other unexpected errors. There are numerous Stack Exchange questions and blog posts out there that deal with it, for e.g. [this one](https://blog.hazrulnizam.com/understanding-cron-environment-variables/).